# SOA #315 Transformation of Random variable Solution review

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to teach myself the math to pass the P exam and I was wondering if someone could tell me the error in my thinking for this problem.

**Problem**: The random variable $Y_1 = e^{X_1}$ characterizes an insurer's annual property losses, where $X_1$ is normally distributed with a mean 16 and a standard deviation 1.5. Similarly, the random variable $Y_2 = e^{X_2}$ characterizes the insurer's annual liability losses, where $X_2$ is normally distributed with a mean 15 and a standard deviation 2.

The insurer's annual property losses are independent of its annual liability losses.

Calculate the probability that, in a given year, the minimum of the insurer's property losses and liability losses exceeds $e^{16}$

The book I have has the solution to the problem

P(min($Y_1,Y_2$) > $e^{16}$) = P($Y_1$ > $e^{16}$) * P($Y_2 > e^{16}$) = 0.5 * 0.3085

I was wondering why there is no need to calculate the probability that $X_1$ > $X_2$ then do a linear combination (idk if the linear combination is the right word but I'll show my work)

My Work: Since $X_1$ $\sim$ N(16,$1.5^{2}$) and $X_2 \sim N(15, 2^2)$ we have

$X_1 - X_2 \sim N(1, 2.25^2)$. P(min($X_1,X_2) = X_1)$ = 0.3446

And P(min($X_1,X_2) = X_2)$ = 0.6554

So:  P(min($Y_1,Y_2$) > $e^{16}$) = 0.6554 * 0.3085 + 0.3446 * 0.5 $\neq$ 0.5 * 0.3085

I was wondering what was wrong with my logic and what my solution is actually telling the math to if there is any kind of of logic to my work. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your logic behind $X_1>X_2$?

Comment: I am looking to see where each random variable becomes the minimum

Comment: O.K., but both random variables do it independent from the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Adding an answer because it is too long for a comment.*

What you are trying to do is compute the probability using the Law of Total Probability as follows:
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\min\{Y_1, Y_2\} > a) & = \Pr(\{\min\{Y_1, Y_2\} > a \} \cap \{Y_1 > Y_2\}) +  \Pr(\{\min\{Y_1, Y_2\} > a\} \cap \{Y_1 < Y_2\}) \\  
& = \Pr(\{Y_2 > a\} \cap \{Y_1 > Y_2\}) +  \Pr(\{Y_1 > a\} \cap \{Y_1 < Y_2\}) \\
& = \Pr(\{Y_2 > a\} | \{Y_1 > Y_2\})\Pr(Y_1 > Y_2) +  \Pr(\{Y_1 > a\} | \{Y_1 < Y_2\})\Pr(Y_2 > Y_1).   
\end{align*}
However, you are plugging in $\Pr(\{Y_2 > a\} | \{Y_1 > Y_2\}) = \Pr(Y_2 > a)$, which is incorrect. If you try plugging in the correct value of the conditional probability above, you will end up obtaining the same expression as suggested in the solution.